# Google Classroom, Ruby, Rails: @NotGoogleAppsUser with test account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-apps, google-classroom

I've got a test account for Classroom from Google (that is, all services apart from Classroom are disabled for it). Following the example as in https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/ruby (with slight modifications), I'm able to log in and fetch details e.g. about the student's courses.

However what I want to do is utilize it in a Rails app. I'm using `omniauth-google-oauth2` and `google-api-ruby-client` (the new 0.9.x branch). After having fetched the token for that test account from Google (I've triple checked that it is *this account* and not any other profile I use) I'm trying to access data from `Google::Apis::ClassroomV1::ClassroomService`, but it keeps telling me:

```
Sending HTTP get https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?pageSize=10
403
#<Hurley::Response GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?pageSize=10 == 403 (319 bytes) 748ms>
Caught error forbidden: @NotGoogleAppsUser The user is not a Google Apps user.
Error - #<Google::Apis::ClientError: forbidden: @NotGoogleAppsUser The user is not a Google Apps user.>

Google::Apis::ClientError: forbidden: @NotGoogleAppsUser The user is not a Google Apps user.
```

The code I use is:

```
require 'google/apis/classroom_v1'

module GoogleIntegration::Client
  Classroom = Google::Apis::ClassroomV1

  def self.create(token)
    service = Classroom::ClassroomService.new
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly', 'profile', 'email']
    service.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
    service.authorization.access_token = token
    service.client_options.application_name = 'Membean Classroom Sample'
    service
  end
```

and in the controller:

```
service = GoogleIntegration::Client.create(request.env['omniauth.auth'].credentials.token)
response = service.list_courses(page_size: 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Classroom API [Access Errors](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors):

> ***NotGoogleAppsUser*** indicates that the requesting user does not belong
>   to a Google Apps domain.
>
> *Possible Action*: Prompt the user to re-authenticate using a "Google
>   Apps for Education" account. Provide a link to using [multiple
>   accounts](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977) so the
>   user can select the correct account.

Comment: Nope, the user is, as I said, a test account (in classroom-dev.com domain) from Google, which is a valid Classroom-enabled acount as I have managed to access its details using code from https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/ruby. It's just that that Rails gem doesn't seem to be able to work with it.